# update list of map value with matching value from another list of map

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have two datasets similar to the below. I am trying to update the id value in map2 to the corresponding di2 value in map1.

```
map1({id1:1 value:2 :valueb:4 id2:a}{id1:2 value:2 :valueb:4 id2:b}{id1:3 value:2 :valueb:4 id2:c})
map2({id:1 x:1 y:2}{id:2 x:4 y:6}{id:3 x:1 y:3})
```

So the output would look like:

```
map3({id:a x:1 y:2}{id:b x:4 y:6}{id:c x:1 y:3})
```

Any help appreciated, not sure how to go about this one..

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data is really

```
(def map1 (list {:id1 1, :value 2, :valueb 4, :id2 'a}
                {:id1 2, :value 2, :valueb 4, :id2 'b}
                {:id1 3, :value 2, :valueb 4, :id2 'c}))

(def map2 (list {:id 1, :x 1, :y 2}
                {:id 2, :x 4, :y 6}
                {:id 3, :x 1, :y 3}))
```

... then

```
(let [im (into {} (map (juxt :id1 :id2) map1))]
  (map #(assoc % :id (im (% :id))) map2))
```

... produces what you are looking for:

```
; ({:y 2, :x 1, :id a} {:y 6, :x 4, :id b} {:y 3, :x 1, :id c})
```

First, we build, in `im`, a map of the required translations from `map1`; then we apply it, map by map, to the `:id` entries in `map2`.

This is pretty clearly a relational algebra thing, but I can't find a standard function or combination of functions to fit. [Here](https://github.com/tailrecursion/bacwn) might be a reasonable place to look.